# How to input Chinese on CentOS7 using system input method?

Tags: input-method

I would like to be able to type in Chinese. I've tried to set it as `system input` Chinese (Intelligent Pinyin) without success. I am running Emacs on `CentOS7`.

I can input Chinese on anywhere except on emacs. For example, I can input Chinese on Gnome-Text-Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Interectively:

Alt+x set-input-method, then give "chinese-py"

In the init.el configuration file

```
(setq default-input-method "chinese-py")
```

Ref: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_chinese_input.html

Comment: Thanks! But, I want to use system input method.

Comment: See this post: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=33926

Comment: I have read that post. I'm so sorry.  In my case,  I can input Chinese anywhere except on emacs.